# Как организовать конференцию на ActionScript3, используя NetGroup и RTMPF Cirrus?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Народ, нужно сделать конференцию на ActionScript3. Нужно, чтобы человек 5-10 разговаривали в одной конференции. Дайте ссылок чтоли, либо скиньте кусок кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- На основе [Adobe Cirrus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/)  -  [пример кода](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/rtmfp_cirrus_app.html).
- Более сложный на Flash Media Server (или бесплатном аналоге), [примеры](http://www.adobe.com/content/dotcom/en/devnet/flashmediaserver/samples.html).
- У адобе где-то был список партнеров, которые оказывают подобные услуги, оплачиваешь аккаунт и хостишь столько клиентов для конференций, сколько нужно.